# Understanding potential energy abstractly and its connection to entropy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, potential-energy

From what I understand, each particle has an energy called kinetic energy. When we consider a system of particles, in addition to their individual kinetic energy, there is an energy associated with the systems which depends on their relative configuration which we call the potential energy. Mathematically a system of particles can be analysed at the individual particle level by assuming that system of particles induces a field and associate potential energy for each particle and then sum up over particles to get the potential energy for the system of particles.

So I thought that potential energy is some sort of energy associated with the field (which is a mathematical construct). But later I studied that fields are real and they have their own energy.

So is the potential energy the same as field energy, if not how are they related? Additionally, just as the energy of a particle is decomposed as potential and kinetic energy, can we do the same for the field, i.e., potential field energy and kinetic field energy? If so, then how is the potential energy of the particle related to the potential energy of the field?

Also, potential energy in my mind is related to the shape a system of particles takes. Changing shape releases or absorbs energy. Entropy is a concept which is also related to the structure/order of the system. So how does the entropy relate to the potential energy?

Answer (score 1):

Potential energy is a function of configuration of material system, e.g. of positions of massive particles.

When this potential energy is expressible as integral of some field over physical 3D space, this energy can be re-ascribed to field in that space, instead of to that system of particles. To some extent, it is arbitrary to what the energy is ascribed. It starts to matter in relativistic theory, where things are nice when all EM energy can be localized, that is, ascribed to the field (space) instead of to particles.

So for example, the Coulomb potential energy of two charges can be expressed as energy of EM field in the whole (infinite) space.

Entropy has many different meanings and they do not have anything directly to do with potential energy. Entropy is linked, in definition, to multiplicity or to probability, not to energy.